# Using postmessage to communicate with iframe - where is the error?

Tags: javascript, iframe, greasemonkey

I have a Greasemonkey script that should send a postmessage to an embedded iframe where the same script starts a function. My attention is sending an easy message to trigger a function inside the iframe. The website and the iframe are not on the same domain. My js skills are quite bad and I can't find the issue.

Thx for reading

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Test
// @namespace   
// @include     domainA
// @include     domainB
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

if ("domainA" === location.hostname)
{
  if (window === top) // prevents the script from running twice on domain A
  {
    window.setTimeout(delay, 15000);
    function delay()
    {
      console.log("Delay");
      document.getElementsByTagName("Iframe")[0].contentWindow.postMessage('message', 'domainB');  //The issue is probably here
    }
  }  
}
else // domain B 
{ 
 window.onmessage = function()  // or here
 {  
  console.log("Done"); // Didnt start
 }
}
```

edit: Iam using Firefox

Comment: What are you using for that second `postMessage` argument? Is it a domain name or a URL? The origin parameter should be `http://some.domain.com` (or similar) not `some.domain.com`.

Comment: Iam using `https://domain.com`

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe you can do this within one script.  If you create two scripts it will work.  Make sure each script only includes the one domain.

First script that gets the iframe and posts the message to it:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Test
// @namespace   
// @include     domainA
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

if (window === top) // prevents the script from running twice on domain A
{
  window.setTimeout(delay, 15000);
  function delay()
  {
    console.log("Delay");
    document.getElementsByTagName("Iframe")[0].contentWindow.postMessage('message', 'domainB');  //The issue is probably here
  }
}
```

Second script that matches the domain of the iframe and attaches the event handler:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Test IFrame
// @namespace   
// @include     domainB
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

if (window.addEventListener) 
{
    window.addEventListener("message", function (event) 
    {  
        console.log("Done");
    }
}
else  // IE8 or earlier
{
    window.attachEvent("onmessage", function (event)
    {
        console.log("Done");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried, but am getting a strange error if I add your code my `console.log("Delay");` didn't fire and so probably the rest of the code.

Comment: The Iframe contains a embedded videojs player from openload.co

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I have no access to the iframe html so I tried to add the script code with Greasemonkey. I found this code in an older question on stackoverflow. There is something i missing. Is there a way to check the iframe for my insert code?

Edit// Ok nvm `rawframe.contentDocument` is not working if i add `console.log("rawframe.contentDocument")` to my script it return NULL and the `script.text` line is blocking my hole script if i comment it out `console.log("Delay")` is working again.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Test
// @namespace   
// @include     https://domainA.com
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==
if (window === top) // prevents the script from running twice on domain A
{
  var rawframe = document.getElementsByTagName("Iframe")[0];
  var framedoc = rawframe.contentDocument;  // is NULL
  if (!framedoc && rawframe.contentWindow)
  {
    framedoc = rawframe.contentWindow.document;
  }
  var script = doc.createElement('script');
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.text = "window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {console.log("Done");}";
  framedoc.body.appendChild(script);

  window.setTimeout(delay, 15000);
  function delay()
  {
    console.log("Delay");
    document.getElementsByTagName("Iframe")[0].contentWindow.postMessage('message', 'https://domainB.com');  
  }
}
```

Comment: If you split the scripts into two and make sure that Greasemonkey only matches them to their respective domains.  You can just attach the event handler without needing to mess around with injecting any JavaScript.  I have updated my answer to reflect that you don't have control of the iframe.